# How to create Hotpatchable Image for .NET dll?

Tags: .net, windows, hotpatching

I had read about the ability to update Windows Server OS without rebooting it using [Windows Hotpatching](http://jpassing.com/2011/05/03/windows-hotpatching-a-walkthrough/) functionality. MSDN says that Hot Patching can be enabled for VC++ projects with a [simple switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173507.aspx).

Is there a similar switch/setting for .NET projects? If no, is it possible to do so using an external tool?

Comment: sounds like the compile & continue function of visual studio ...

Comment: @user287107 Not sure what you meant there. When you have Hotpatching capability, you can patch your dll without rebooting the machine or restarting the application. This can be easily enabled for VC++ dlls as mentioned in the link but I could not find any links/resources to enable this feature for .NET dlls.

Comment: in visual studio, you can apply code changes and continue. that is like hotpatching. the debugging process is interrupted, a new codebase is loaded, and the execution continues. visual studio can do this under specific assumptions for .Net

Comment: To the best of my understanding, hotpatching never really worked properly.  I would guess that the switch is only still present for backwards compatibility.